# jQuery animation sometimes fails to fully complete

Tags: jquery, animation

```js
$("p").mouseenter(function() {
     $("p").stop( true ).animate({
 left: '+=100px',
     },1000);
});
 
 
$("p").mouseleave(function () {
    $("p").stop( true ).delay(100).animate({
       left: '-=100px',
    },1000);
});
```

```css
p{
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Text</p>
```

I've had a running glitch while using the jQuery `animate` function. If I quickly enter and exit my cursor into the element onto which the animate function is attached; the animation is incomplete. This may be an unclear explanation; so I've posted by code. Try quickly entering your cursor into the `p` and playing with it to see how it glitches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `mouseleave` set left to `5px` instead of minus `100px`, every-time on mouse leave whatsoever the position of text it has to go `-100px` which sometime hides text, so it's better to stop that at initial assigned value.

```js
$("p").mouseenter(function() {
     $("p").stop( true ).animate({
 left: '+=100px',
     },1000);
});
 
 
$("p").mouseleave(function () {
    $("p").stop( true ).delay(100).animate({
       left: '5px',//Change this
    },1000);
});
```

```css
p{
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text</p>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work; since I would want the p to return to its original position upon mouseleave.

Comment: @MullerA That returns to original position which is 5px on mouseleave.

Comment: Welcome @MullerA :-), Every-time mouseenter it moves text 100px forwards because of +=

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/77oar74e/

```js
$("p").mouseenter(function() {
     $("p").stop( true ).animate({
 left: '+=100px',
     },1000);
});
 
 
$("p").mouseleave(function () {
    $("p").stop( true ).delay(100).animate({
       left: '5px',
    },1000);
});
```

```css
p{
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text</p>
```